# Swift 3 how to tap on tab bar to scroll to the top of the table view

Tags: uitableview, swift3

Here's my code from various sources that detects if the tab bar is tapped the second time.

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
        var previousController: UIViewController? = nil
        if previousController == viewController {
            // the same tab was tapped a second time
            print("scroll to top")
            if viewController.responds(to: #selector(self.scrollToTop)) {
                viewController.perform(#selector(self.scrollToTop))
            }
        }
        previousController = viewController
    }

    func scrollToTop() {
        self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0 - self.tableView.contentInset.top))
    }
```

When I tap the tab bar a second time, print("scroll to top") isn't called. What could be the issue here with my code?

Answer (score 0):

This is may be because you are getting nil, and so it is not going in if condition

```
 var previousController: UIViewController? = nil
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare 'previousController' as an instance of that class in which you are detecting the tap.

```
var previousController: UIViewController? = nil
```

Your above line of code will always be initialized to nil every time you tap on tab bar and if condition will never result in true.

Comment: what do you mean by declaring previousController as an instance of that class?

Comment: you should create it as a variable that will be visible in that class like this

    class smapleClassName: UIViewController {
        var previousController: UIViewController!
        
        override func viewDidLoad()    {
            super.viewDidLoad()        
        }